# task eats 100% cpu on Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I got app server with MongoDB installed.

Every 3 hours I run some nodejs script that updates data, and my server consumes 100% CPU and becomes slow.

Is there any way to improve that?

Can I create another db instance (cluster), and run the script only on one of them and sync them ?